# Best setting to create a tarball faster

Tags: amazon-web-services, tar

My goal is to create a **dummy.tar** file containing all my files&dirs in a **dummy** directory, which sums up to several TB of information. Moreover, I want this to go as fast as possible.

I created the following setting in AWS for this purpose:

- c5.xlarge (4 cores and 8GB ram)
- one hdd containing the mentioned **dummy** dir
- one hdd for **dummy.tar**

Then I run:

```
tar -cf /path/to/mount2/dummy.tar /path/to/mount1/dummy
```

But unfortunately this is going way to slow, about 5M/s for both disk read and write, knowing that these disks are capable of much more (at least 10x more). I also noticed that the process is consuming little cpu and that using an ssd for **source.tar** did not help.

Therefore what I want to know is whether this can go faster and if so what should I change in my current setting.

Thank you for your attention.

**Edit:**

Note: I can also accept alternatives to **tar**, as my ultimate goal is to create a file containing multiple files/dirs, without regard to compression.

Meanwhile I also tried:

- other types of aws instances, such as t2.medium and i3.large
- perform the operation using only one disk for both source and target, still it did not help

Comment: Does it need to a single file? I'm pondering if you could download the AWS drive as an iso, skip the whole zipping step entirely.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't download it.